# Why OpenMP atomic and critical don't give the right result?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have written the following Fortran code to test `atomic` and `critical`

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer::i
    integer::a(10),b(10),atmp(10),btmp(10)
    a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    b=[12,32,54,77,32,19,34,1,75,45]
    atmp=a
    btmp=b
    write(*,'(1X,10I4)') a+b
    print*,'------------------'
    !$omp parallel
    !$omp do
    do i=1,10
        B(I) = B(I)+A(I)
    end do
    !$omp end do
    !$omp single
    write(*,'(1X,10I4)') b
    !$omp end single

    a=atmp
    b=btmp
    !$omp do
    do i=1,10
        !$omp critical
        B(I) = B(I)+A(I)
        !$omp end critical
    end do
    !$omp end do
    !$omp single
    write(*,'(1X,10I4)') b
    !$omp end single

    a=atmp
    b=btmp
    !$omp do
    do i=1,10
        !$omp atomic
        B(I) = B(I)+A(I)
        !$omp end atomic
    end do
    !$omp end do
    !$omp single
    write(*,'(1X,10I4)') b
    !$omp end single

    !$omp end parallel
end program
```

The output is

[image]

It means that result of `atomic` and `critical` is wrong. This is strange, I thought adding them could avoid racing condition. However, the first loop without synchronization gives right answer, is there no racing here? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the expected right result? is it above the line? It would be better to include these as text. The picture could be deleted by the hosting after some time.

Comment: I think the race condition is actually the `a=atmp;    b=btmp` in the parallel region. But I didn't study the code for too long.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  I saw this kind of usage on page 92 here http://openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-examples-4.0.2.pdf . The doc show this as an typical usage of atomic, is it not right?

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you. You are right! Add single to a=atmp and b=btmp, the result is right. But do you think `atomic` is needed here? Will it improve performance? If not , what is the meaning of the doc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem in your code is the race condition

```
   !$omp parallel

...
    a=atmp
    b=btmp
...
    !$omp end parallel
```

all threads do that operation and they clash. You want `omp single` around these lines.

You don't need any `atomic` or `critical` in

```
!$omp do
do i=1,10
    B(I) = B(I)+A(I)
end do
!$omp end do
```

because each thread operates on a different array element.

In your example from the OpenMP specification the issue is that in

```
!$OMP   PARALLEL DO SHARED(X, Y, INDEX, N)
DO I=1,N
  !$OMP       ATOMIC UPDATE
  X(INDEX(I)) = X(INDEX(I)) + WORK1(I)
```

the array or function `INDEX(I)` can return the same value for two different threads with a different `I` and you must protect this potential race condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer!